# Which criterion should we consider if we need to choose between cassandra and bigcouch?

Tags: database, networking, cassandra, p2p, bigcouch

What are the pros / cons? Which of the both would better fit in a P2P client?

Answer (score 2):

For a public p2p service?  Neither.  http://www.quora.com/Distributed-Systems/Which-is-the-most-popular-routing-technique-for-distributed-hash-tables